# Linux - Open nth File LIsted

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ls

I'm Ubuntu, I do `ls` and get a list of files.  How would I open the nth file in the list in VIM in reference to its position from the `ls` command, and not its name? I want to do this cause a directory has a lot of files with long, similar, names.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ vim .
```

starts a new vim instance showing a listing of the current directory. Move your cursor on the one you want to edit and hit `<Enter>`.

Comment: is there a similar way to open something in a video player, Parole, or with gnome-open?

Comment: @appleLover, try ranger or vifm, they are CLI file managers with vi-like key bindings.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [do not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This can lead to all sorts of issues, the most common being that it will break on file names that contain spaces or newlines. A safer way would be to use `find`:

```
$ vim "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  | awk 'NR==12')"
```

If you really want to use `ls` and know that your file names are safe, you could do (make sure to use quotes as I have done, otherwise, this breaks on file names with spaces):

```
$ vim "$(ls -1 | awk 'NR==12')"
```

That will open the 12th file, change the number according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First start a Vim instance with all files in the directory in the *argument list*:

```
$ vim *
```

This will open the very first file. To go to file 42, use

```
:42argument
```

Note that in order to quit Vim, you now need to use either `:argdel *`, or quit via `:q!`; else, Vim warns you about `more files to edit`.

You can also combine this:

```
$ vim -c 42argu -c 'argdel *' *
```